# Passing function as props in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

How can I pass a setter function (useState) as prop using navigation.navigate? I have it set up as the following:

```
const [firstName, setfirstName] = useState('');
  const [dob, setDOB] = useState('');
  const [medicalConditions, setMedicalConditions] = useState('');
  const [allergies, setAllergies] = useState('');
  const [bloodtype, setBloodtype] = useState('');
  const [height, setHeight] = useState('');
  const [weight, setWeight] = useState('');
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding">
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile', {
            setMedicalConditions: (a) => setMedicalConditions(a),
            setAllergies: (b) => setAllergies(b),
            setBloodtype: (c) => setBloodtype(c),
            setHeight: (d) => setHeight(d),
            setWeight: (e) => setWeight(e)
          })}
          style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOutline]}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Edit</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )
```

It works fine but I get an error saying :

```
Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state. Check:

Profile > params.setMedicalConditions (Function)

This can break usage such as persisting and restoring state. This might 
happen if you passed non-serializable values such as function, class 
instances etc. in params. If you need to use components with callbacks in 
your options, you can use 'navigation.setOptions' instead. See 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting#i-get-the-warning-non-
serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state for more details.
```

I tried using DeviceEventEmitter but it says it's deprecated.

Comment: why you didn't use redux ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a setter function with `navigate` to another component!

What you have to do is to create a function that updates your state and pass it to the child component instead of all these setter functions.

The function will recieve two parameters, the first is to indicate which state to update, and the second is for its new value :

```js
const updateState = (stateName, newValue) => {
  switch (stateName) {
    case "weight": setWeight(newValue)
      break;
    case "height": setHeight(newValue)
      break;
    case "bloodtype": setBloodtype(newValue)
      break;
    case "allergies": setAllergies(newValue)
      break;
    case "medicalConditions": setMedicalConditions(newValue)
      break;
    default:
      console.log("strange state");
  }
}
```

Now this function you can pass it to the child component

```js
onPress={() => avigation.navigate("Profile", {
    updateState: (a,b) => updateState(a,b),
})};
```

And use it to update state in the parent one

```js
updateState('height', 1.85);
```

This will update the `height` state in the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create function X in screen A(contain setter) and pass to screen B. when you call function X in screen B, setter is called.

```
  const functionX = (newValue) => {
   setHeight(newValue);
   }
```

and

```
>  navigation.navigate('Profile', {
>         setHeight: (d) => functionX(d),  
>       })}
```

if you only want to save value, use    **useRef()** insted